# Delphi error while returning TList

Tags: delphi

I have made a very simple application but I have an issue that I really cannot understand. Look at this basic code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, generics.collections, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    test: TList<integer>;
    aList: TList<integer>;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function testGenerics: TList<integer>;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 test := testGenerics;
 test.Sort;
 showmessage(test[0].tostring);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 test := TList<integer>.Create;
 aList := TList<integer>.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
 aList.Free;
 test.Free;
end;

function TForm1.testGenerics: TList<integer>;
begin

  aList.Add(4);
  result := aList;

end;

end.
```

Basically when the Form opens I am going to create `test` and `aList` and then when I press the button the function `testGenerics` is called. Why do I have the *Invalid pointer operation* error?

I really cannot understand since I am creating and destroying the objects (I guess) properly. This code instead works fine:

```
function TForm1.testGenerics: TList<integer>;
begin

  Result := TList<integer>.Create;
  Result.Add(4);

end;
```

In this case I am returning an instance of `TList<integer>` but also in the case above I am returning an instance of `aList` (which is a TList).

If I'm correct in the first case `test := testGenerics` is like `test := aList` (because I am returning aList in fact) so I am going to give `test` the same reference as `aList`. Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, whenever you call `testGenerics()`, you are re-assigning `test` to point at the `aList` object.  You are losing track of the original `test` object created in the `OnCreate` event, so it is leaked.  And then in the `OnDestroy` event, when you call `test.Free`, it crashes because you already freed the `aList` object beforehand, so you are trying to free the same object a second time, which is an invalid operation.

In the second example, you are still leaking the original `test` object (and every `TList` you allocate and assign to `test`, except for the last one), but you are not re-assigning `test` to point at the `aList` object anymore, so there is no crash in the `OnDestroy` event because both variables are pointing at separate objects.

---

What are you trying to accomplish in the first place?  Returning objects in this manner is not good practice.  Nor does it make sense to call `Sort()` on 1-element lists.

If you are trying to populate `test` with multiple values over time, you should pass `test` as an input parameter to `testGenerics()` (or just let `testGenerics()` access `test` directly via `Self`), don't use the return value at all.

And in any case, get rid of your `aList` private member, as you are not doing anything with it anyway.

Try this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, generics.collections, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    test: TList<integer>;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure testGenerics(aList: TList<integer>);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  testGenerics(test);
  test.Sort;
  ShowMessage(test[0].tostring);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  test := TList<integer>.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  test.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.testGenerics(aList: TList<integer>);
begin
  // FYI, a better way to exercise Sort()
  // would be to use RandomRange() instead
  // of a hard-coded number...
  aList.Add(4);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you Remy! to fix the leak I should use the 2nd example and remove the creation of test in FormCreate? Then the test.free inside ondestroy is fine from what I have undeestood

Comment: That will only prevent a leak the first time you call `testGenerics()`, but will still leak on subsequent calls since you are not calling `test.Free` before calling `testGenerics()`.